# How to change the value of the DateTimePicker before dropdown

Tags: .net, datetimepicker

I want to change value when DateTimePicker  is dropdown

```
protected override void OnDropDown(EventArgs eventargs)
    {

        if (Value == MinDate)
        {
            Value = DateTime.Now;
        }
        base.OnDropDown(eventargs);

    }
```

but don't work ,Input box is displayed today, but the  Calendar is displayed  MinDate.
   I want  the  Calendar is displayed  today.And I have a solution，But It's not what I want,I do not want to send message to system

```
protected override void OnDropDown(EventArgs eventargs)
    { 
        if (Value == MinDate)
        {
            Value = DateTime.Now;
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("%{DOWN}");
        }
        base.OnDropDown(eventargs); 
    }
```

sorry,My English is not good!